Find the index of the first non-null value in a column in a polars dataframe
I need to find the first non-null value in a column over a grouped pl.DataFrame.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["s1", "s1", "s2", "s2"],
        "trade": [None, 1, -1, None],
    }
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ -1    │
│ s2     ┆ null  │
└────────┴───────┘

How can I get the row numbers/index values of the first non-null value in the trade columns while group_by symbol?
I am actually looking for the row/index numbers 1 and 0. Maybe the result could be something like this:
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ first-non-null │
│ ---    ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════════╡
│ s1     ┆ 1              │
│ s2     ┆ 0              │
└────────┴────────────────┘

I am actually looking for the equivalent to pd.first_valid_index()

Here's one way using .arg_true().first():
print(
    df.group_by("symbol").agg(
        pl.col("trade").is_not_null().arg_true().first().alias("first-non-null")
    )
)

Output:
┌────────┬────────────────┐
│ symbol ┆ first-non-null │
│ ---    ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ u32            │
╞════════╪════════════════╡
│ s1     ┆ 1              │
│ s2     ┆ 0              │
└────────┴────────────────┘


Very elegant approach!

Follow-up question: I need to assert that the values in the original dataframe at these positions in each group are different from zero. In my example, this would evaluate to True.

Maybe it's easier to operate on a list column? df.group_by("symbol").agg(pl.col("trade"))

assert df.group_by("symbol").agg(pl.col("trade")).with_columns(first=pl.col("trade").list.first()).filter(pl.col("first") == 0).is_empty()
